# htaccess unwanter 301 redirect and POST data loss

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an MVC PHP application and in xampp works great, but in linux hosting is not working properly and when it comes to send POST data via form the htaccess (without any order) gives a 301 redirect and the POST data is lost forever...

here is my htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /devel

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

With browser i can see that there is a 301 for post data and 200 (ok) for get data...

please anyone knowr why i have this 301 redirect before the normal redirect? In my script there is no header() function (not in the form nor in the destination page of course) and my hosting (Aruba.it) doens't have the mod_proxy enabled, so i can't use P flag for POST redirecting...

Ah i tried also

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
```

but without any result.

Tank for any reply!!!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

It came out it was a server redirect: i had a global var that contain the domain url "domain.com" to avoid writing it in my entire script. When it comes to call urls, the server auto rewrites "domain.com" in "www.domain.com" with a 301 http message. I changed the value of the var and everything works fine now!!!